# Resize Image with AppleScript

Tags: image, resize, applescript, geektool

I've encountered a little problem when I wanted to modify a ApplScript, that I am using to get my current iTunes Coverinto a image file that I display on my Desktop via GeekTool.
Now I wanted also to resize this Image because some Images are a bit small...

I found some solutions online, but none of them worked...
And since I am not that much into AppleScript I also can't handle it myself.

This is my current Code:

```
set the_artwork_file to ((path to home folder) as string) & "Music:iTunes:CurrentArtwork.png"
tell application "System Events"
if ("iTunes" is in name of processes) then
    tell application "iTunes"
        if (player state is not stopped) 
            and (player state is not paused) 
            and (artworks of current track exists) 
            then
            set theArt to front artwork of current track
            set pic to (raw data of theArt)
            try
                set RefNum to (open for access the_artwork_file with write permission)
                write (pic) to RefNum
                close access RefNum
                return
            end try
        end if
    end tell
end if
end tell
do shell script "rm -f " & (POSIX path of the_artwork_file)
```

Ok, nevermind, I managed to solve it finally.
The Code I generated was basically correct, but I had to put it into an separate Script-File.
In GeekTool I have to call them directly after each other and it works just fine!

This is the Code I used now:

```
tell application "Image Events"
    set this_image to open ((path to home folder) as string) & "Music:iTunes:CurrentArtwork.png"
    scale this_image to size 1080
    save this_image in ((path to home folder) as string) & "Music:iTunes:CurrentArtwork.png"
    close this_image
end tell
```